# Assess synchronization for Asynchronous loader

Tags: c++, synchronization, mutex

I'd like to receive advice how to solve the following problem.

```
// Asynchronous loader
class AsyncLoader
{
void SendRequest()
{
std::tr1::bind(&AsyncLoader::OnSendRequest,this,std::tr1::placeholders::_1));
mutex.lock();
// send some request
}

void OnSendRequest()
{
mutex.unlock();
}

TSomeType GetCachedValue()
{
mutex.lock();
TSomeType ret = cachedValue;
mutex.unlock();
return ret;
}


TSomeType cachedValue;
Mutex mutex;

}
```

Also have client who sends requests using **AsyncLoader** to update **cachedValue** from backend. Sometimes I don't need to send request , I can ask **AsyncLoader** the cached value by calling **GetCachedValue()**.
Sometimes I have synchronization problem when one client sends request to update data, but other client calls **GetCachedValue()** to receive cached value.
It is clear that I should use mutex to synchronize assess - but I'm confused by fact, that I should lock mutex in **SendRequest()** and call unlock in other function **OnSendRequest()**. It seems to me such solution is potential dead lock if something happened during request and **OnSendRequest()** will not be called.

Other idea was to have real cached value to copying value from previous request - but I'd like to minimize memory usage.

P.S: Maybe even here I can talk about the problem - the use of an object only when it is fully initialized. If object is not initialized yet I should wait it.
Best regards, Roman.

Comment: I have changed code to illustrate my problem - I guess there is some mismatch, the question was not about recursive mutex.